# How can I write Action for redux action generators?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

those are the actions.

```
export const fetchProductsStart = () => ({
  type: ProductListActionTypes.PRODUCT_LIST_START,
});

export const fetchProductSuccess = (products: IProduct) => ({
  type: ProductListActionTypes.PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
  payload: products,
});

export const fetchProductFailure = (error: any) => ({
  type: ProductListActionTypes.PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE,
  payload: error,
});
```

I wrote Action like this:

```
export type Action =
  | ReturnType<typeof fetchProductsStart>
  | ReturnType<typeof fetchProductSuccess>
  | ReturnType<typeof fetchProductFailure>;
```

I passed this to the reducer's Action type

```
 case ProductListActionTypes.PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, products: action.payload };
    case ProductListActionTypes.PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
```

I got warning for `action.payload`. it says "Property 'payload' does not exist on type Action"

Answer (score 1):

Not every branch in the `Action` union has a `payload` key, and the compiler does not know which branch to take, since the `type` of the action is widened to just `string` instead of   `'PRODUCT_LIST_START' | 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS' | 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE'`

If you look at the type of `Action` it is

```
type Action = {
    type: string;
} | {
    type: string;
    payload: IProduct;
} | {
    type: string;
    payload: any;
}
```

This is because `ProductListActionTypes` is inferred as

```
const ProductListActionTypes: {
    PRODUCT_LIST_START: string;
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS: string;
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE: string;
}
```

The compiler can then not determine which branch of the `Action` union you want, it cannot discriminate which action type it is, because the type has been widened to `string`.

You can fix this by adding `as const` to the end of the `ProductListActionTypes` declaration.

```
export const ProductListActionTypes = {
  PRODUCT_LIST_START: 'PRODUCT_LIST_START',
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS: 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS',
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE: 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE'
} as const;
```

and then the type of `ProductListActionTypes` is inferred as

```
const ProductListActionTypes: {
  readonly PRODUCT_LIST_START: "PRODUCT_LIST_START";
  readonly PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS: "PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS";
  readonly PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE: "PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE";
}
```

and then `Action` is

```
type Action = {
    type: "PRODUCT_LIST_START";
} | {
    type: "PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS";
    payload: IProduct;
} | {
    type: "PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE";
    payload: any;
}
```

And now the compiler knows which branch of the `Action` union to take when you give it one of the action types.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to utilize [Discriminated Union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions#exhaustive-checks). But the Typescript assumes the action to be of type:

```ts
type Action = {
    type: string;
} | {
    type: string;
    payload: any;
} | {
    type: string;
    payload: any;
}
```

And, thus it cannot distinguish types in `switch` statement. What would be helpful here if we can show that `type` is going to be `'PRODUCT_LIST_START' | 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS' | 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE'`. If we can tell Typescript that our `ProductListActionTypes` is going to be unchanging i.e. we need to [const assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) this object.

We can do constant assertion like this:

```ts
const ProductListActionTypes = {
  PRODUCT_LIST_START: "PRODUCT_LIST_START",
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS: "PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS",
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE: "PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE",
} as const;
```

And now our `Action` type looks like this:

```ts
type Action = {
    type: "PRODUCT_LIST_START";
} | {
    type: "PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS";
    payload: any;
} | {
    type: "PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE";
    payload: any;
}
```

And, you'd not see the wavy lines.

[See full code at Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL99ZW)